# How to make your object act as another type when comparing?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I do not remember how to do in C# a comparison of a class against a primitive type.

Example

```
public class Validate{
... //This is here that we would need to add code 
    //if I remember to make the object act as a boolean for example
}

...

Validate v = new Validate(...);
if(v==true)
{
...
}
```

Do you know the name of that and how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Custom Object Validation Design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290251/c-custom-object-validation-design)

Comment: what behavior are you expecting? Do you want to be able to control that yourself? I mean, do you want v to be true when there is an object, or when it suits your criterias?

Comment: I want that v be compared to True/False. I do not want to use property or method...

Comment: Yes, but what do you expect True/False to represent? An object that exists might have faulty values, is it still "true" then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for an [implicit type conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Add the following method to your Validate class:

```
    public static implicit operator bool(Validate v)
    {
        // Logic to determine if v is true or false
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thank you sir!

Comment: @Daok, I do not think this is exactly what you want. Don’t use an implicit operator unless you can meaningfully and reliably map all possible values of `Validate` to a value of `bool`. If you just want to do `== true` and `== false`, then I recommend the operator overload solution provided by *hunter* below.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want, you need to override the implicit cast operator:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private int i;

    public MyObject(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(MyObject o)
    {
        return o.i % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

The above example will evaluate to true if the field `i` is even:

```
MyObject o1 = new MyObject(1);
MyObject o2 = new MyObject(2);

if (o1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("o1");
}

if (o2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("o2");
}
```

The output of the above is `o2`.

---

However, it is a bit of a horrible implementation as it leads to confusing code in that you have constructs that read as `if (object)`, which would be unfamiliar to most readers - `if (object.IsValid)` makes the intention much more clearer.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean operator overloading?

```
public static bool operator == (Validate v, bool value) 
{
    return /* some comparison */
    // or going off of the other posters answer
    return v.IsValid == value; 
}
```

Comment: He wants to be able to compare the class Validate with a boolean.

Comment: yeah, I know. I think you can accomplish this by overloading the `==` and `!=` operators. Only thing that came to mind

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `IsValid` property to your `Validate` class and call that property:

```
public class Validate
{
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { [implementation here] }
    }
}

...

Validate v = new Validate(...);
if(v.IsValid)
{
    ...
}
```

It is possible to create an implicit operator, but it is not advisable to use it this way, because it would make your code hard to follow for other developers.

**UPDATE**

Okay, just for completeness and education, this is how to do it:

```
public class Validate
{
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { [implementation here] }
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(Validate v)
    {
        return v.IsValid;
    }
}
```

But again, don't do it. It would make your code pretty hard to follow.

Comment: That doesn't allow you to do `v == true` does it?

Comment: @Filip: Nope, and I consider that a good thing. If that really is what the OP wants, he should implement a `public static implicit operator bool(Validate v)` method on the `Validate` type.

Comment: @Daok: I know you don't want that, but please don't do it.